# 7zip CRC data of files in packed archive

Tags: hex, 7zip

I just faced with the next problem. I need to get CRC data of files in packed archive 7z. I have found docs (http://www.7-zip.org/recover.html) that describes how is 7z works with integrity of the packages but unfortunately I didn't found answer.

Do you have any ideas how to get CRC file's data from packed 7zip archive without unpacking it?

Answer (score 5):

```
7z l -slt archive.zip
```

should list extended info for the files in the archive, including CRC if it was added at the creation time

Answer (score 2):

if you are asking this here at SO I understand you want to do it programmatically.

OK just get the file Client7z.cpp from 7z source code.
That file creates Client7z.exe which is able to list the files in a 7z file.
If you see the code it is easy to also list the CRC by just adding

```
{
  // Get CRC of a file
  NWindows::NCOM::CPropVariant prop;
  archive->GetProperty(i, kpidCRC, &prop);
  UString s = ConvertPropVariantToString(prop);
  PrintString(s);
  PrintString("  ");
}
```

with this info you could also quickly code your own application based on Client7z.cpp fitting only your specific needs.